# Rounded time doesn't match the real time

Tags: php, date, time

I made a little script which supposed to take a time in seconds, round it to the next full quart of an hour and then put it in a date(H:i).

This is what i've made:

```
$seconds = '5940';
$rounded_seconds = ceil($seconds / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60); 
// This rounds up to 6300 seconds = 105 minutes = 1.45 hours

$rounded = date('H:i', $rounded_seconds);
```

`$rounded` gives me `02.45` as a result. What did I do wrong here?

Update:

In another topic I was told to downgrade my code here to what's important. I thought I did, but maybe I left out to much, so here is the whole code:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($klanten); $i++) {


     $seconds[$i] = $results_distance[$i]['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']; //gets value 5940

//if I echo $seconds[$i] here, i get: 5940
                   
     $rounded_seconds[$i] = ceil($seconds[$i] / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60); //rounds to full quarters

//if I echo $rounded_seconds[$i] here, i get: 6300
                                               
     $rounded[$i] = date('H:i', $rounded_seconds[$i]);

 //if I echo $rounded[$i] here, i get: 02:45 instead of 01:45
                               
 }
```

Output:

[Output script including the array for the loop, data from the array is not used in the script with the troubles. But the script is running inside the for loop to read the array.][1]

At the moment there are 2 items in the array.
I think it looks like $rounded doubled (the two times the for loop runs).. but then I think it is strange that the other echo's return a single value..

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGzjG.png
```

Comment: I run that code and get `01:45`

Comment: I also got 1:45 (DST issue?)

Comment: please post details on how you determined that $rounded gave you 02.45 as a result

Comment: In another topic I was told to downgrade my code here to what's important. I thought I did, but maybe I left out to much, so I have posted the whole code in my opening post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a timezone issue, this should work. When I run this in a UTC timezone the right answer of `01:45` is produced.

```
$tz = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$seconds = '5940';
$rounded_seconds = ceil($seconds / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60); 
// This rounds up to 6300 seconds = 105 minutes = 1.45 hours

$rounded = date('H:i', $rounded_seconds);
echo $rounded;

// return to your real timezone
date_default_timezone_set($tz);
```

Comment: I tried, but no luck. I changed my opening post in the orginal code, I am afraid I left out to much code in the first place.

Comment: Tis works, see the demo https://3v4l.org/IlHik